# How to get how many hour minute seconds laps on message on php mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to get how many hour minute seconds laps on message on php mysql?

like

23 seconds ago
1 minute ago

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple way is using the jQuery plugin timeago http://timeago.yarp.com/
The neat thing about it is, that it updates the entries while viewing the page :)

Answer (score 0):

In db table create field `time` INT(10). Insert in this filed php `time()`.

In script check diff:

```
$diff = time() - $time_from_db;
echo $diff . 'seconds ago'.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to have the data fed from the database you could write SQL like this:

```
SELECT FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date)) / 86400) as days FROM your_table
```

(MySQL example)

You could should then repeat for hours, minutes etc. subtracting the reminder.

From your result you would have `$result['days']` available.

This said I would go for the timeago solution mentioned by Tim. But it is hard to say not knowing your application.